# Issue with credential login along with database adapters in nextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm facing issue while logging in with my credentials once I use the database adapters, I'm new to this so need a little help here, When I use adapter I can't login with my credentials. Any help in this will be appreciated

```
import { User } from "@/models/User";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongoConnect";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

async function getUser() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return session?.user;
}

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      id: "google",
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      id: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "test@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const email = credentials?.email;
        const password = credentials?.password;

        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        const passwordOk = user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

        if (passwordOk) {
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I have tried using "session:{strategy:"jwt"} in my next-auth after which the session is looked in the cookie I guess but now my google provider won't work

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code that worked for me with mongoDB adapter. I can login with credentials and google provider both after which I am redirected to the homepage.

```js
import { User } from "@/models/User";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongoConnect";

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      id: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "test@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const email = credentials?.email;
        const password = credentials?.password;

        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        const passwordOk = user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

        if (passwordOk) {
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, credentials }) {
      const { email } = user;

      // Connect to MongoDB
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);

      // Check if the user exists in the database
      const dbUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });

      // If no Google profile provided, login with credentials
      if (!profile || !profile.name) {
          return true;
      }

        // If the user does not exist and is signing in with Google and Google email is verified
        if (
          !dbUser &&
          account?.provider === "google" &&
          profile.email_verified
        ) {
          console.log("Creating new user...");

          // Create a new user object
          const newUser = new User({
            name: profile.name,
            email: profile.email,
            image: profile.picture,
          });

          // Save the new user to the database
          await newUser.save();
          console.log("New user created:", newUser);

          return true
        }
      
        // Login if email exists and has Google account
        return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session, account }) {
      delete token.name;
      delete token.email;
      delete token.picture;

      if (!token.user) {
        token.user = {};
      }

      // construct the data held in Session for user
      if (user) {
        const userData = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          image: user.image,
        };
        token.user = userData;
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token.user) {
        session.user = token.user;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return url.startsWith("/") ? baseUrl : url;
    },
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: The refreshToken part was for Microsoft login, I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `authOptions` from a recent project. `authorize()` is used to check credentials.

In `signIn()`, I check for the user email exists along with a password, if so then they signed up with email.

If not then if they have an email and account.

Also you will see I used `allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true` in the providers. I couldn't get it to work without this.

Then when using SignIn for buttons use it like this:

```
// credentials sign-in
await signIn('credentials', {
  ...data,
  redirect: false,
});

// google sign-in
await signIn('google', {
   callbackUrl: '/dashboard'
});
```

```
// authOptions
import { NextAuthOptions, User } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import { z } from 'zod';

import { env } from '@/env.mjs';
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';
import { AccountApprovalStatus, UserData, UserRole } from '@/types/user';
import { createSlug } from '@/utils/createSlug';
import { verifyPassword } from '@/utils/password';
import { zodSafeValidateValue } from '@/utils/validate';

const loginSchema = z.object({
    email: z
        .string({
            required_error: 'Email is required',
        })
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .email({ message: 'Enter a valid email address' })
        .max(80, { message: 'Email no longer than 80 characters' }),
    password: z
        .string({
            required_error: 'Password is required',
        })
        .trim()
        .min(8, { message: 'Password must be at least 8 characters' })
        .max(80, { message: 'Password no longer than 80 characters' }),
});

const GOOGLE_PROVIDER = 'google';
const AZURE_PROVIDER = 'azure-ad';

function getGoogleCredentials() {
    const clientId = env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    const clientSecret = env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;

    if (!clientId || clientId.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID');
    }

    if (!clientSecret || clientSecret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET');
    }

    return { clientId, clientSecret };
}

function getAzureCredentials() {
    const clientId = env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID;
    const clientSecret = env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const tenantId = env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID;

    if (!clientId || clientId.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID');
    }

    if (!clientSecret || clientSecret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET');
    }

    if (!tenantId || tenantId.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID');
    }

    return { clientId, clientSecret, tenantId };
}

async function updateLastLogin(email: string) {
    await prisma.user.update({
        where: {
            email: email,
        },
        data: {
            lastLogin: new Date(),
        },
    });
}

async function refreshAccessToken(token: JWT) {
    try {
        console.log('refreshedToken TOKEN', token);

        const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${getAzureCredentials().tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

        const body = new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: getAzureCredentials().clientId || 'azure-ad-client-id',
            client_secret: getAzureCredentials().clientSecret || 'azure-ad-client-secret',
            scope: 'email openid profile User.Read offline_access',
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: token.refresh_token as string,
        });

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body,
        });

        const refreshedTokens = (await response.json()) as {
            token_type: string;
            scope: string;
            expires_in: number;
            ext_expires_in: number;
            access_token: string;
            refresh_token?: string;
            id_token: string;
        };

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw refreshedTokens;
        }

        console.log('########## REFRESH TOKENS ########', refreshedTokens);

        return {
            ...token,
            access_token: refreshedTokens.id_token,
            expires_at: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
            refresh_token: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refresh_token,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            ...token,
            error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
        };
    }
}

const providers = [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: getGoogleCredentials().clientId,
        clientSecret: getGoogleCredentials().clientSecret,
        // Allow automatic account linking
        allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
        authorization: { params: { access_type: 'offline', prompt: 'consent' } },
    }),
    AzureADProvider({
        clientId: getAzureCredentials().clientId,
        clientSecret: getAzureCredentials().clientSecret,
        tenantId: getAzureCredentials().tenantId,
        authorization: {
            params: { scope: 'openid email profile User.Read  offline_access' },
        },
        httpOptions: { timeout: 10000 },
        allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'Credentials',
        credentials: {
            email: {
                label: 'Email address',
                type: 'email',
                placeholder: 'jsmith@example.com',
            },
            password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            const formData = {
                email: credentials?.email,
                password: credentials?.password,
            };

            const validateInput = zodSafeValidateValue(formData, loginSchema);
            if (!validateInput.success) {
                throw new Error('Email or password may be incorrect');
            }

            // check to see if user exists
            const data = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email: credentials?.email,
                },
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    firstName: true,
                    lastName: true,
                    avatar: true,
                    email: true,
                    password: true,
                    account: true,
                },
            });

            if (!data) {
                throw new Error('Are you sure your email and password are correct? Try logging in with Google.');
            }

            if (!data.password || data.account.length > 0) {
                throw new Error('Log in with Google or reset password');
            }

            // check to see if password matches
            const isPasswordMatched = await verifyPassword(credentials?.password as string, data.password);

            if (!isPasswordMatched) {
                throw new Error('Email or password may be incorrect');
            }

            // set lastLogin
            await updateLastLogin(credentials?.email as string);

            const user: User | null = {
                id: data.id,
                firstName: data.firstName,
                lastName: data.lastName,
                avatar: data.avatar,
                email: data.email,
            };

            return user;
        },
    }),
];

export const authOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers,
    secret: env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login', // on successful sign-in
        signOut: '/sign-out', // on signout redirects users to login page.
        // newUser: '/intake', // New users will be directed here on first sign-in
        // error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error= // TODO: Add error page
    },
    callbacks: {
        // save user if they login via social networks
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, credentials }) {
            console.log('NEXTAUTH SIGN IN USER', user);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH SIGN IN ACCOUNT', account);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH SIGN IN PROFILE', profile);

            const { email } = user;

            const userSelection = {
                firstName: true,
                lastName: true,
                avatar: true,
                email: true,
            };

            // Check if user email exists
            const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                where: { email },
                select: userSelection,
            });

            console.log('NEXTAUTH SIGNIN USER FOUND', dbUser);

            if (!profile || !profile.name) {
                return true;
            }

            // If no user and sign-in with Azure AD, create new user
            if (!dbUser && account?.provider === AZURE_PROVIDER) {
                const [firstName, ...lastNameArr] = profile.name.split(' ');
                const lastName = lastNameArr.join(' ');

                const username = createSlug(`${firstName.toLowerCase()}${lastName.toLowerCase()}`, 6);

                await prisma.user.create({
                    data: {
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        email,
                        emailVerified: new Date(),
                        avatar: user.image,
                    },
                    select: userSelection,
                });

                // set lastLogin
                await updateLastLogin(profile.email as string);

                return true;
            }

            // If no user, but sign-in with Google, create new user
            if (!dbUser && account?.provider === GOOGLE_PROVIDER && profile.email_verified) {
                const username = createSlug(
                    `${profile.given_name.charAt(0).toLowerCase()}${profile.family_name.toLowerCase()}`,
                    6
                );

                await prisma.user.create({
                    data: {
                        firstName: profile.given_name,
                        lastName: profile.family_name,
                        email: profile.email as string,
                        emailVerified: new Date(),
                        avatar: profile.picture,
                    },
                    select: userSelection,
                });

                // set lastLogin
                await updateLastLogin(profile.email as string);

                return true;
            }

            // set lastLogin for Google Login
            if (
                (account?.provider === GOOGLE_PROVIDER && profile.email_verified) ||
                account?.provider === AZURE_PROVIDER
            ) {
                await updateLastLogin(profile.email as string);
            }

            return true;
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session, account }) {
            console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT USER', user);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT TOKEN', token);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT SESSION', session);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT ACCOUNT', account);

            delete token.name;
            delete token.email;
            delete token.picture;

            // Ensure token.user is initialized
            if (!token.user) {
                token.user = {} as UserData;
            }

            // Update token.user with user data if user exists
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition
            if (user) {
                const userData: UserData = {
                    id: user.id,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    avatar: user.avatar,
                    email: user.email,
                };
                token.user = userData;
            }

            console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT USER FINAL', token);

            // Add access_token, expires_at, and refresh_token if both account and user exist (Oauth)
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition
            if (account && user) {
                // Refresh the access token if it has expired
                if (account.expires_at && Date.now() >= account.expires_at * 1000) {
                    try {
                        console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT RUN REFRESH ACCESS TOKEN', token);

                        token = await refreshAccessToken(token);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
                    }
                }

                const newToken = {
                    ...token, // Preserve other token properties
                    user: { ...token.user }, // Create a shallow copy of token.user
                    access_token: account.id_token,
                    expires_at: account.expires_at ? account.expires_at * 1000 : 0,
                    refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
                };

                console.log('NEXTAUTH JWT RETURN ACCESS TOKEN', newToken);

                return newToken;
            }

            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            console.log('NEXTAUTH SESSION', session);
            console.log('NEXTAUTH SESSION TOKEN', token);

            if (token.user) {
                const {
                    id,
                    firstName,
                    lastName,
                    avatar,
                    email,
                } = token.user;

                // Assign only the desired properties to session.user
                session.user = {
                    id,
                    firstName,
                    lastName,
                    avatar,
                    email,
                };
            }

            if (token.error) {
                session.error = token.error;
            }

            // If expires_at is available in token, add it to session.user
            if (token.expires_at) {
                session.user.access_token_expires_at = token.expires_at;
            }

            console.log('NEXTAUTH SESSION FINAL', session);

            return session;
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            // Allows relative callback URLs
            if (url.startsWith('/')) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
            // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
            else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;

            return baseUrl;
        },
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
} satisfies NextAuthOptions;
```

Comment: Thanks man, I made some tweaks for mine in the callback and now my login is working with credentials and google provider both.